# If a monkey types each letter of alphabet exactly once, what is the probability of the word "Hamlet" appearing?

Tags: probability

A monkey types each of the 26 letters of the alphabet exactly once (the order is random). What is the probability that the word Hamlet appears somewhere in the string of letters?

#### Progress

So far I thought that Hamlet is a 6-letter string and could appear in 21 different spots in the 26-letter string. But what should I do next? That is, what is the number of possible sequences of the other letters and the total probability?

Comment: So far I thought that Hamlet is a 6-letter string and could appear in 21 different spots in the 26-letter string. But what should I do next? That is, what is the number of possible sequences of the other letters and the total probability?

Comment: Well, break that question into parts. What is the number of possible sequences of the other letters? You should be able to reason out the answer for a fixed Hamlet-location; so try a couple of locations and see if you notice a pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT:** First count how many possible $26$-letter strings there are. Now, abbreviate Hamlet to H, and use the remaining $20$ letters along with H.

Comment: Are we assuming h = H, i.e., lowercase and upper is identical here?

Comment: Yes, no caps distinction!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For each of these $21$ places in which you can put the substring *hamlet* the other letters can be permuted in $20!$ ways, for a total of $21\times20!=21!$ strings containing the word *hamlet*. How many strings of $26$ distinct letters can be typed?

Answer (score 0):

If the 26 letters are the only keys the monkey is allowed to press then my answer is 0% because the monkey wouldn't be able to change from upper case to lower case because that "Shift" key is not one of the 26 allowable keys typed.  hamlet or HAMLET would be possible but not mixed case Hamlet like the question states you are looking for.

As the original question is written, my answer seems correct so if you meant hamlet or HAMLET or the Monkey will always type a capital H and always lower case for all the other 25 letters then please clarify that.

Comment: This is not a forum for trick questions!

Comment: @Winther, as the question is stated, my conditional answer of 0% seems correct.  The author could have easily asked for hamlet and not Hamlet.  To me that is a significant difference of what is being asked and a "lesson" for authors to be accurate when they ask a question in this forum.  Word problems in general are "tricky" because how can the reader know what to and what not to assume?  What are the general "rules" about making assumptions for questions like this when certain pieces of information are not divulged? I "conditioned" my answer based on a certain interpretation.

Comment: Again, this a math forum and the question is about probability - not words. As you can see, it was pretty clear to everybody else answering/commenting.

Comment: @Winther, word problems need to be worded accurately, otherwise answers like mine here have merit.  Imagine if this was a question asked in school and a student gave the same answer as me.  He/she could argue it is correct to the teacher.  I feel this question (and many other word problems on this site) are not worded well, perhaps the authors are being lazy.  This question has other ambiguities as well.  For example, would hamlet spelled backwards (telmah) be an acceptable answer? The question asked for Hamlet to appear somewhere, it didn't say in the "forward" read direction only.

Answer (score 0):

Alessandro and Ted have both given good hints.

Some things to keep in mind are the following:

1.) The monkey is typing each of the 26 letters of the alphabet, not just 26 random letters on the page. Thus, instead of $26^{26}$ possibilities for the message typed, we are left with a much smaller number.

2.) Since the strings we're interested in have Hamlet written somewhere, your intuition about having $21$ locations to place Hamlet is correct. However, in each of these states, the $20$ remaining letters (all unique remember) can be permuted in any fashion. So, if we have $21$ places for our 'Hamlet' block and in each position the remaining $20$ letters can be permuted as desired...

If you can calculate the total number of possible messages from (1) and the total number of messages with Hamlet in them from (2), you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

Take some random arrangment of the $26$ letters.

There are $26P6$ possible strings of $6$ letters and each of them has equal probability to arise as the string on the numbers $i,i+1,\dots,i+5$.

So the probability that this will be the string "hamlet" is: $$\frac{1}{26P6}$$

Further there are $21$ candidates for $i$ so the probability that string "hamlet" arises somewhere is: $$\frac{21}{26P6}$$